# Eclipse RCP 4 adds new tab/part in an IEventBroker handleEvent

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, e4

In a normal command handler I can add new tab/part as this code:

```java
@Execute
    public void execute(Shell shell, EPartService partService, MApplication application,EModelService modelService) throws URISyntaxException{
        MPart part = MBasicFactory.INSTANCE.createPart();
        part.setLabel("New file ");
        part.setCloseable(true);
        part.setContributionURI("bundleclass://com.xxx.rcp.app.item_editor/com.xxx.rcp.app.item_editor.parts.ItemEditorPart");
        List<MPartStack> stacks = modelService.findElements(application, "com.xxx.rcp.app.partstack.2", MPartStack.class, null);
        stacks.get(0).getChildren().add(part);
        partService.showPart(part, PartState.ACTIVATE);
    }
```

Now I want to add new tab/part in one IEventBroker handleEvent.

First, I register the topic in the Activator:

```java
@Override
    public void start(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
        IEclipseContext serviceContext = EclipseContextFactory.getServiceContext(context);
        IEventBroker eventBroker = serviceContext.get(IEventBroker.class); 
        eventBroker.subscribe("MY_TOPIC", ContextInjectionFactory.make(OpenItemEditorHandler2.class, serviceContext));
}
```

Then, I add the tab/part in handleEvent:

```java
public class OpenItemEditorHandler2 implements EventHandler {

//  @Inject 
//  private IEclipseContext serviceContext;

//  @Inject
//  EPartService partService;

//  @Inject
//  MApplication application;

    @Inject
    IEclipseContext serviceContext;

//  @Inject
//  EModelService modelService;

//  @Inject
//  private ECommandService commandService;
//  
//  @Inject
//  private EHandlerService handlerService;

@Override
    public void handleEvent(Event event) {
MPart part = MBasicFactory.INSTANCE.createPart();
        part.setLabel("New file ");
        part.setCloseable(true);
        part.setContributionURI("bundleclass://com.xxx.rcp.app.item_editor/com.xxx.rcp.app.item_editor.parts.ItemEditorPart");
        // get the part stack and show created part 
        EModelService modelService = serviceContext.get(EModelService.class); 
        MApplication application = serviceContext.get(MApplication.class);
        List<MPartStack> stacks = modelService.findElements(application, "com.xxx.rcp.app.partstack.2", MPartStack.class, null);
}
```

I cannot access or inject those services because of null all. Why? I have injected my object `OpenItemEditorHandler2` in the `Activator`.

Or can you give some hints about other solutions to add new tab/part?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The context returned by `EclipseContextFactory.getServiceContext` only has OSGi services, it does **not** contain most of the normal e4 services so you can't use this to create your class. This means that the activator is not a suitable place to set up your subscribe.

You need to set up the subscribe somewhere where you have access to a proper eclipse context. An `AddOn` or the RCP `LifeCycle` might be suitable.

In an `AddOn` constructor you might have:

```
@Inject
public MyAddon(IEclipseContext context, IEventBroker eventBroker)
{
  eventBroker.subscribe("MY_TOPIC", ContextInjectionFactory.make(OpenItemEditorHandler2.class, context));
}
```

Comment: I added a new addon to the application model. In the bundleclass I added the code as in the `Activator`. But the `handleEvent` was not called. About `LifeCycle`, those code is in a plugin for another RCP app. How to add the `LifeCycle `? Thanks!

Comment: You can only use the LifeCycle in the main RCP plugin. The code in the AddOn should **not** be using `EclipseContextFactory.getServiceContext`, Inject the `IEclipseContext` directly. See updated answer

Comment: Thanks, greg! The code worked. But there is an issue: In `MyAddon`, I just can inject those services to method/constructor but field.

Comment: Note that you must have the `@Inject` on the constructor as I showed to use constructor injection.